# mysql left join returns unexpected amount of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, mysql-num-rows

I have 2 tables where

```
tableA has 41 rows
```

and

```
tableB has 3 rows
```

I am trying to get the total rows of these 2 tables via a query using left join but i get way more rows(123) than expected(44)

query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM tableA as u
LEFT JOIN tableB as d
    ON u.uid=d.uid
WHERE
    u.uid=912391178669
    AND
    u.deleted = 0
    AND
    d.deleted=0
```

tables schema:

**tableA**

id | uid | deleted

**tableB**

id | uid | deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run the following query It is working correctly.. U can check it out.

```
SELECT 
  ( SELECT count(*) from table1 where.... )
+ ( SELECT count(*) from table2 where.... )
as total from dual
```

Comment: I believe it would be as correct without `SUM()`. And I'm not sure if MySQL supports `FROM DUAL`, but I know for certain that you can omit it.

Comment: ohhh ya
actually I was trying two query at the same time so I think i mixed it up...
yes without sum also its working...

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you have three rows in tableA with the uid given in the query. That will mean that each row in tableA will join once with each row in tableB, which means you will back 41 x 3 rows or 123.

From the number of rows you are expecting back, I wonder if you need a Union instead of a join.

```
Select * from tableA where uid = 912391178669 and deleted = 0

union all

Select * from tableB where uid = 912391178669 and deleted = 0
```

A union will combine the results of two queries. A join will combine the columns of table tables in a single query.

Comment: my edited query looks like : Select count(id) as total from tableA where uid = 912391178669 and deleted = 0
union all
Select count(id) as total from tableB where uid = 912391178669 and deleted = 0 but when i run it in phpmyadmin i get total|41|3 when i run it in on a script it shows just 41 returned back... how can i make it sure the sum?

Comment: @fxuser: I think Jeff's idea was to lead you to something like this: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( /* the UNION query here */ ) somealias`.

Answer (score 0):

```
41*3=123
```

each row of TableA has uid=912391178669 and tableB each row also have uid that's why you are getting 123 row total. use some filter criteria to get desired result (like some `AND` condition)

if you can show us your table column then it may be possible to help you .

Left join does not combine the rows of two table .
TableA left join TableB will give you all the row of table A meeting the joining condition.

Comment: i have added the schema on the question

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tableA as u
LEFT JOIN tableB as d
ON u.uid=d.uid
AND
u.deleted = d.deleted
WHERE
u.uid=912391178669
AND u.deleted = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(
  (SELECT count(*) from tableA WHERE uid=912391178669)
+ (SELECT count(*) from tableA WHERE uid=912391178669)
 ) as totalRows
```